# How to improve this Regular expression validation?

Tags: javascript, php, regex

I tried to write a form validation for description textarea> of the users about their owns like he/she education or experience.
I wrote this Regex for this textarea, but I have a problem if user use above comma it's not allowed, for example if user written "House's", it's not allowing to write this comma '.
PWhich symbols may needed or predicate while users describe owns?

I used this Regex:

```
$descriptionValidation = "/^[a-zA-Z0-9\.\-\,\"\(\) ]+[a-zA-Z0-9\.\-\,\"\(\) ]*$/";
```

Comment: Is this an attempt to prevent SQL/XSS injections? You also are over escaping In character classes `.`, `(`, `)`, and `,` have no special meaning. The regex doesn't allow quotes. Please provide reproducible example. https://regex101.com/r/AL869r/1/ Also add/explain JS aspect.

Comment: @user3783243 thanks it's solved my problem, again thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To match a whole string and require that the string only consist of alphanumeric characters and: dots, commas, single-quotes (also called apostrophes, but not "above commas"), double-quotes, left parentheses, right parentheses, spaces, and hyphens, use the following expression.

The `^` and `$` metacharacters ensure that the characters span the entire length of the string. `+` means one or more of the any of the characters in the list.  The "list" is technically called a "character class".  `a-z` is the full range of letters and `\d` is the full range of numbers.  `-` does have special meaning inside of a character class but only if it has a non-ranged expression on both sides of it.  If you wish to prevent mistakes with hyphens inside of a character class, you can add a backslash to escape it or you can write the hyphen at the start or end of the character class OR you can write it next to a character range.

```
/^[a-z\d.,'"() -]+$/i
```

When declaring this pattern in php using single quotes, you will need to escape the single-quote in the character class.

```
$descriptionValidation = '/^[a-z\d.,\'"() -]+$/i';
```